# count words with for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, text-mining, arabic

I use R for text mining in Arabic language 
and I would like to check on words if it the word have more than 6 character do the some change

and it is working but it return the first word only 
here is my code

```
LL<- "بنزين سائقين تعملين مخينعو ينام"
    n2<- length(LL)
    for (i in 1:n2 ){
         for (j in 1:n2){
            o[j] <-(strsplit(LL[i], " "))
                    K<-ifelse(nchar(o[[j]][j])>=6 ,gsub('(?<=\\p{L})\\x{064A}\\x{0646}$', '', o[[j]][j], perl = TRUE),o[[j]][j])
                    return( print(K))
         } }

  [1] "بنزين"
```

and I think I need to add j++ 
but I don’t know where should I add it 
thank you

Comment: Could you explain in more detail what you are trying to achieve? Ideally with an explicit example of desired outcome. The use of a *double* loop is not very clear.

Answer (score 2):

You can perform that task without any loop

```
words <- unlist(strsplit(LL, " "))
nchar(words)
# returns
[1] 5 6 6 6 4
```

The rest could probably also be performed using vectorization e.g.

```
K <- character(length(words))
K[nchar(words) < 6] <- words[nchar(words) < 6]
K[nchar(words) > 5] <- gsub('(?<=\\p{L})\\x{064A}\\x{0646}$', '', 
                            words[nchar(words) > 5], perl = TRUE)
# result
K
[1] "بنزين"  "سائق"   "تعمل"   "مخينعو" "ينام"
```

---

On a side note:

- you are using `return` inside a loop - I do not think that is the proper way to use it. A simple `print(...)` would suffice.
- also, whenever a result is not of expected size and `ifelse` is involved, you might want to check the length of the condition statement as that will determine the size of the result.

Comment: thank you, it's worked but I was used (for loop) because I want to run it through data frame so i want it to go row by row.

Comment: also I want to save the changes on the same row

Comment: This last task - much like most tasks in `R` - can also be performed vectorized e.g. `cbind(words,K)`.